# Mapstruct null checking target field for no reason

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have the following class structure -

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class ParentDTO {

String type;
List<String> tags;
}

@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Getter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public ChildDTO extends ParentDTO {
  String child;
  ....  
}


@Getter
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class ParentBO {
  String type;
  List<String> tags;
}

@Getter
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ChildBO extends ParentBO {
  String child;
}
```

I am using mapstruct to map from DTO to BO and the mapper has the following code -

```
    @SubclassMapping(target = ChildBO.class, source = ChildDTO.class)
    ParentBO backward(ParentDTO parentDTO);
```

For some reason when the Mapstruct generates code for this mapping it checks for null in target childBO object's list attribute before assigning the list value from the DTO object, which results in ChildBO's list always being null.

```
    @Override
    public ParentBO backward(ParentDTO parentDTO) {
        if ( parentDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        if (parentDTO instanceof ChildDTO) {
            return childDTOToChildBO( (ChildDTO) parentDTO );
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not all subclasses are supported for this mapping. Missing for " + parentDTO.getClass());
        }
    }

    protected ChildBO childDTOToChildBO(ChildDTO childDTO) {
      if (childDTO == null) {
        return null;
      }
      String child = childDTO.getChild();
      ChildBO childBO = new ChildBO(child);
      if (childBO.getTags() != null) { // Why this check
        List<String> list = childDTO.getTags();
        if (list != null) {
           childBO.getTags().addAll(list); // And why not a new list here?
        }
      }
    }
```

Can someone help me understand why it is happening? I have mapped other lists before and have never faced this problem.

Comment: Is it possible that you configured the collection mapping strategies with ADDER_PREFERRED. https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#collection-mapping-strategies